# No audio since upgrade to 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04

Well, not really. Its a gamble actually. When booting, kernel module responsible for audio sometimes loads and sometimes crashes. After several reboots I get the sound.

Here's dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5634866/

I tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but it hangs for 10 minutes already. I'm fairly sure nothing is happening.

Any ideas?